# Hide and show 2 overlapped divs with 2 buttons, jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlap

I am new to html css animation with jquery.
Here is my problem if someone has the time to answer.

[image: details image]

THE RED is my first div with a button on it,
THE BLUE is the second one.
They have exactly the same size, and the red is on top of it.

What i want to do is when you click on the button "click" the RED DIV with the button hide, and let show the blue one with the cross.
and when you click on the cross the first div come back with the button.

I know this is a common question but i am really lost.
Thank you

Code example:

```
<div id="reddiv">
  <button id="submitbutton">click</button>
</div>
<div id="bluediv">
  <button id="closebutton">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have tried ? First of all try the samples search it in google lot of samples is there and make it as easy

Comment: i've tried something with the function switchVisible() { if and else and display style but i really can't do it -_-

Comment: take a look [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/8xh4Lnjk/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it, but there are lots of different ways to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/3vg6xm79/

Jquery #1

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
   $('div').css('z-index', 1);
    $(this).css('z-index', 0);
});
```

you could also do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/3vg6xm79/1/:

Jquery #2

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
   $('div').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

html

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Css

```
.red, .blue{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: i'll try it too the but the Steph answer look better to me, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to add a class to your elements insteed of a single property as it allows more flexibility and change of future styles so as my answer is simillar to @Chanckjh I would use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.click-here').click(function () {
                $('.box2').addClass("z-index");
                $('.box1').removeClass("z-index")                
            });
    $('.cross').click(function () {
                $('.box1').addClass("z-index");
                $('.box2').removeClass("z-index")                
            });
        });
```

here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/979y8cx5/2/)**

Comment: i'll try it too the but the Steph answer look better to me, but thank you!